# How to write a validation for array with dependable key value pairs?

Tags: laravel, validation

```
  "title" => array:2 [
    0 => null
    1 => null
  ]
  "description" => array:2 [
    0 => null
    1 => null
  ]
```

This array will always be sent like that, BUT only one pair of values is needed (title + description)

- everything null is not allowed
- If title.0 is filled, description.0 is required and also if description.0 is filled title.0 is required
- If title.1 is filled, description.1 is required and also if description.1 is filled title.1 is required
- both titles and descriptions can also be sent

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Tomorrow  I'll post what I've tried. I'm not at work anymore.

Comment: @lewis4u I've updated my answer, give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

The following is just a pseudo code:

```
if title.0 is empty and description.0 is not empty
    return title.0 is required
else if title.0 is not empty and description.0 is empty
    return description.0 is mandatory
end-if
```

You then do the same validation for title.1 and description.1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. First, clean the `null` values before the validation is performed:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

// ...

public function prepareForValidation()
{
    $original = $this->all();

    $filtered = Arr::where($original, function ($value, $key) {
        return ! is_null($value);
    });

    $this->replace($filtered);
}
```

Then specify this rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title.0' => 'required_without:title.1',
        'title.1' => 'required_without:title.0',
        'description.0' => 'required_with:title.0',
        'description.1' => 'required_with:title.1',
    ];
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.